# Interaction effects for independent variables in percentages

Tags: interaction, percentage

If the Independent variables are in percentages, then will it make sense to calculate interaction effects using the original figures? or do I need to make any changes?

Comment: on the face of it, looks unproblematic, but for an informed answer we want to have some context, please!

Comment: I'd say that it's potentially problematic -- because near the bounds the response can't be additive, even if it's additive near the middle. This nonlinearity makes interpreting interactions on the original scale confounded with interpreting nonlinear "main effects". More details would help, but typically I would not be working with a model on the original scale; I'd expect to use a nonlinear link function.